# Issues of pointing to same or different objects

Tags: objective-c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let's see a example:

***Scenario 1:***

NSString *str1=@"Hello";// str1 points to a literal string @"Hello"

NSString *str2=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:str1];

NSLog(@"%p %p",str1,str2);// str1 and str2 both point to same object

***Scenario 2:***

NSString *str3=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello"];

NSString *str4=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:str3];

NSLog(@"%p %p",str3,str4);// str3 and str4 point to different objects

I want to know the difference between scenario 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

It is an implementation detail (and indication that there is an optimization that Foundation *could* do that it isn't).

You should never assume that two objects are equal or unequal based on pointer equality.  Pointer equality is only useful for checking if they are literally the same object.  `isEqual:` must be used to check if they are semantically identical.

Under the covers, Foundation knows that `@"Hello"` is a constant string and creating a second immutable string from a constant string can just return the constant string.

It is assuming that `initWithFormat:` will produce a non-constant string.  The optimization opportunity is that Foundation could, during parsing of the format string, detect that no formatting was done and just return the constant string (I'm kinda surprised it doesn't-- I should file an <strike>bug</strike>enhancement request).

Comment: So you want to tell me it's a bug?

Comment: @Symon: No, that's not what he said. It's an implementation detail. For any string-typed expression you can imagine, if the result has the same value as some existing string object, it's *possible*/*legal*/*valid* for the implementation to produce the identical object (same address). It's also possible/legal/valid for it to produce a separate object. You must not depend on it doing one or the other, specifically.

Comment: @Symon Nope;  not a bug.  A minor missed performance optimization.  And what Ken said;  **you cannot assume pointer inequality means object inequality**.